# Check value of multiple columns and then assign vaue to column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
C1 | C2 |... email_id | subject | sender | recipient
   |    |             | congrats| x      |  y
   |    |             | congrats | z     | y
   |    |             | congrats | x     |y
   |    |             | meeting  | x     | y
```

Output:

```
   C1  | C2 |... email_id  | subject  | sender | recipient
       |    |       0      | congrats | x      | y
       |    |       1      | congrats | z      | y
       |    |       0      | congrats | x      | y
       |    |       2      | meeting  | x      | y
```

For every unique combination of subject, sender and recipient I want to assign an emai_id. I have gotten unique triples like this:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sender','recipient','subject'])
```

In order to assign value this is what I am doing

```
sender = df1.sender
recipient = df1.recipient
subject = df1.subject
n = 0
for i in sender:
     df.loc[df["subject"] == str(i) and df["subject"] == str(i) , "email_id"] = n
     n=n+1
```

This isn't the correct way to go about it. How do I add an "add" condition here?
Edit: In short, assign same number to same triplets

Comment: I think you need merge by left join.

Comment: How would that assign value to email_id?

Comment: If not working merge, please add some sample data - [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your merge code and expected output.

Comment: @jezrael check again

Comment: hmmm, so need `df['email_id'] = df.groupby(subset=['sender','recipient','subject'], sort=False).ngroup()` ?

Comment: What is ngroup()? @jezrael

Comment: Changed dupe answer.

Comment: So change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain why solution with ngroup not working.

Comment: @jezrael it is working fine. I was printing the wrong df. Thanks